# couchdb virtualbox host address

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking, couchdb

I installed ubuntu 14 in virtual box. I use win8 as native os.

After installed couchdb on virtual ubuntu. Now couchdb hosts on localhost and works.

I set virtual connection in virtualbox with 192.168.137.1 ip.

How can I access my couchdb from my win8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right solution the next:

just replace '**bind_address**' in couch db configuration with '`0.0.0.0`'.